# Windows Phone Error HRESULT 89721500

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have been working on an app with the Windows Phone 8 SDK and Visual Studio 2012. I installed VS 2012 Update 3. After that, I started encountering a "Silverlight 4 SDK not found" error. I reinstalled VS 2012 and the Windows Phone 8 SDK which has apparently fixed that error.

I have a new problem now though. The WP8 emulator is not found anywhere on my system. The drop down in VS that shows all of the emulator target options is empty except for just "Start." Choosing "Start" results in VS showing error HRESULT 0x89721500.

Please help me if anyone of you solved this nasty problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem and fixed it by deleting this folder:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\11.0`